# Why can't we use RuntimeException instead of creating custom exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

1. I have been searching a lot on when exactly we should go creating custom exceptions. I found this example:

   ```
    public class IncorrectFileExtensionException extends Exception {
        public IncorrectFileExtensionException () {

        }

        public IncorrectFileExtensionException (String message) {
            super (message);
        }

        public IncorrectFileExtensionException (Throwable cause) {
            super (cause);
        }

        public IncorrectFileExtensionException (String message, Throwable cause) {
            super (message, cause);
        }
    }
   ```

   What's the real value in providing the above custom exception? **Instead of creating the above custom exception, why can I not throw a new RuntimeException("error occurred", e)?** I have seen many examples on the internet creating similar custom exceptions, but I don't understand what the real benefit in the above approach is.

   **If we create something like `IncorrectFileExtensionException`, then our project ends up with many custom exceptions.**
2. I also found this:

   ```
    public class MyUncheckedBusinessException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8460356990632230194L;

        private final ErrorCode code;

        public MyUncheckedBusinessException(ErrorCode code) {
            super();
            this.code = code;
        }

        public MyUncheckedBusinessException(String message, Throwable cause, ErrorCode code) {
            super(message, cause);
            this.code = code;
        }

        public MyUncheckedBusinessException(String message, ErrorCode code) {
            super(message);
            this.code = code;
        }

        public MyUncheckedBusinessException(Throwable cause, ErrorCode code) {
            super(cause);
            this.code = code;
        }

        public ErrorCode getCode() {
            return this.code;
        }
    }
   ```

   This is to some extent better than `IncorrectFileExtensionException`, as we are providing some error code at least. But again, what if all custom exceptions ends up like the above (I mean with an error code)?

   My question is: **What's the best practice for custom exceptions? When exactly should we go for custom exceptions? Is `IncorrectFileExtensionException` really a good approach?**
3. When should we NOT create custom exceptions?

Comment: who says you can't? the point is: you SHOULDN't. If you get an Exception, would you prefer LoggingFailedException and InvalidCertificateException, basically already telling you what is going wrong, or would you prefer to debug everything quite deep, because everything you throw is the same type?

Comment: Imo you should create a custom exception if you want to cat h that exception. Otherwise builtin exceptions should be fine.

Comment: *RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.* - Somehow I think a check exception would be better

Comment: @Stultuske I will be glad , if you could able to explain with some example or providing more explanation. Do you mean if created custom exception, we can able to identify issue easily by seeing our custom exception name, thats what you mean? BTW, how many custom exceptions need to create? I am thinking our project ends up with many such custom exceptions

Comment: If the Exception is *LoggingFailedException* then the code is self-documenting

Answer (score 6):

```
public class MyBusinessRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
    // copy all the constructors you need
}
```

It's a good practice because it helps to group and differentiate error types. You could claim "My API throws `MyBusinessRuntimeException` types" and abstract out other `RuntimeException` types you have no control over. It would tell the user what exception they are going to work with, and what exceptions they should consider as abnormalities.

`IncorrectFileExtensionException` shouldn't directly extend `Exception`. They are on completely different levels of abstraction.

Consider

```
 Exception
     FileException
         FileExtensionException
             IncorrectFileExtensionException
             UnsupportedFileExtensionException
```

Answer (score 5):

Other thing to consider is creating handler for the exceptions.

If you throw two following exceptions: new RuntimeException("User not found") and new RuntimeException("Event not created") how do you handle them? catching every runtime exception and then having if-else that compares messages?

That would be pain in the ass in long term. Same happens when you unit test logic that throws exceptions - you would again have to use if(ex.message.equals(someMessage)) just to have a unit test.

And then what happens when exception messages are the same for different business logic? Just operating with custom exceptions gives you so much ease on handling the flow - from making the catch hierarchy clear to creating some custom solutions that tells handlers how to behave (e.g. tell controller advice to throw 404)

Answer (score 4):

The reason custom exceptions are preferred is because they tell you exactly what's wrong. Having everything as a runtime exception makes it less of a hassle to throw exceptions, yes, but what if you had multiple pieces of code running consecutively that can each go wrong in their own way? There are cases where you'd want to handle each of these exceptions separately and with different logic.

This also allows for better testing in the future. If you would, for instance, want to test if your code runs properly you'd also want to test if your program throws the correct exceptions. By using separate classes you can quickly detect whether or not the correct logic was executed that resulted in that specific exception being thrown.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [SEI CERT Oracle Coding Standard for Java](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR07-J.+Do+not+throw+RuntimeException,+Exception,+or+Throwable) throw `RuntimeException`, `Exception`, or `Throwable` is not a good practice. Therefore you never should throw an `RuntimeException` instead of a subclass.

> Methods must not throw RuntimeException, Exception, or Throwable. 
>   Handling these exceptions requires catching RuntimeException, which is
>   disallowed by ERR08-J.  Do not catch NullPointerException or any of
>   its ancestors.  Moreover, throwing a RuntimeException can lead to
>   subtle errors; for example, a caller cannot examine the exception to
>   determine  why it was thrown and consequently cannot attempt recovery.
>   Methods can throw a specific exception subclassed from Exception or
>   RuntimeException.  Note that it is permissible to construct an
>   exception class specifically for a single throw statement.

Regarding to your concern:

> If we create like IncorrectFileExtensionException, then in our project
>   ends up with many custom exceptions.

You should favor the use of [Built-in](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-exception-in-java-with-examples/)  exceptions available in *Java* libraries, this approach will help you to create less custom exceptions. According to **Joshua Bloch** in his awesome book **Effective Java**:

> Reusing standard exceptions has several benefits. Chief among them is
>   that it makes your API easier to learn and use because it matches the
>   established conventions that programmers are already familiar with. A
>   close second is that programs using your API are easier to read
>   because they aren’t cluttered with unfamiliar exceptions. Last (and
>   least), fewer exception classes means a smaller memory footprint and
>   less time spent loading classes.

The most commonly reused exception type is `IllegalArgumentException`.

For example instead of create a `IncorrectFileExtensionException` class you could throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with a well written error message.

```
...
String message = String.format("'%s' is an incorrect file extension.", fileExtension);
throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
...
```

Therefore you should create a custom exception when you can't reuse a built-in one.