# getting an list of optional type in java

Tags: java

I am getting a list of optional type in java as shown below-

```
final Optional<AbcDTO> fetchList = usersDAO.fetchList(abcCode, abcDTO);
final AbcDTO abcDTO = fetchList.get();
```

I am using JDK 11 and want to have a check that if list(fetchList) is empty, then I want to throw an an runtime exception else I want to continue the list.

Please advise how to do the same.

Comment: Use `.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException())` instead of `.get()`

Comment: @ernest_k request you to please add in the above code itself

Comment: final AbcDTO abcDTO = usersDAO.fetchList(abcCode, abcDTO).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);

Comment: You never should throw an RuntimeException instead of a subclass, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197257/why-cant-we-use-runtimeexception-instead-of-creating-custom-exceptions/58198090#58198090

Answer (score 0):

An `Optional` could either contain an object or not. It does not matter what is in there.

Generally, `.get()` gives you the object which is wrapped in the `Optional`. But if there is no object (it wraps a `null`), you would get an exception.

To check whether the object in there is present, you could just say `OptionalObject.isPresent()`. This returns a `boolean` which tells you whether the `OptionalObject` actually wraps an object.

```
if(fetchList.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
    // Consider not to throw RuntimeExceptions (see comments below)
}
// Continue your programme
```

Actually, `.isEmpty()` is only available since Java 11. In previous versions this could be achieved by negating `.isPresent()`.

```
if(!fetchList.isPresent()) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
// Continue your programme
```

Another, for this situation shorter and easier option is the by @ernest_k suggested one. It gets the element wrapped in the `Optional`. If the `Optional` is empty, the exception mentioned in the `.orElseThrow()` gets thrown. Furthermore, the lambda expression could be converted to a method reference (consider a good exception).

```
AbcDTO abcDTO = fetchList.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

Anyway, this code checks only whether the `List` object is present. For checking further whether the existing `List` has no entries, you could call `.isEmpty()` for the list (not only for the `Optional`).

```
if(abcDTO.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: One can `RuntimeException::new` for `() -> new RuntimeException()`.

Comment: You never should throw an RuntimeException instead of a subclass https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197257/why-cant-we-use-runtimeexception-instead-of-creating-custom-exceptions/58198090#58198090

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek Totally agree. But correct exceptions are another topic. The OP should have a look at this.

Comment: @Michal True. But what is the main difference of this? Readability is sometimes a subjective level and performance should not be affected by this change. Anyhow, it looks fancier. ;)

Comment: IMHO Readability is better with method reference.